# URL Rewrite, Virtual Subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Been struggling with this problem for a while now.

We have a basic online app which you can access at say 
app.domain.co/signup?user=onlinestore

onlinestore is the username of the account.

We want each user to get their own subdomain that they can use the app from.
In this case the subdomain would be onlinestore.domain.co/signup and it would show them the contents as if they were here: app.domain.co/signup?user=onlinestore.

Now as well as that subdomain mirroring the login pages, when they login I would like for all of the pages inside of the app to be able to use the subdomain as well. Ideally I don't want the user to see the app.domain.co domain at all, just their personalised domain. Theres quite a number of pages inside the app so im not sure if theres a simple way for them all to be accessible from any subdomain (if logged in ofc).

Examples:

onlinestore.domain.co will become app.domain.co/signup?user=onlinestore
onlinestore.domain.co/payments will become app.domain.co/payments?user=onlinestore
onlinestore.domain.co/contact will become app.domain.co/contact?user=onlinestore

Current HTACCESS File (in the wildcard subdomain)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.co$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).domain.co
RewriteRule ^$ https://app.domain.co/signup/?user=%1 [L]
```

We've created a wildcard subdomain but it's not working with https, and it's doing a full redirection as opposed to a rewrite, I'm still on shared hosting so I'm not sure if I might have some restraints due to this.

Is there a simple way to do this? I don’t want the users to see the app.domain path at all, just their custom subdomain path.

Comment: With mod rewrite, you can only change the path, as the remote server may reside on a different server, and would have no knowledge of previous mod-rewrite rules. Why not just `RewriteRule ^$ /signup/?user=%1 [L]`

Comment: Would I have to set this up for every file and would the users see the app.domain url?

Comment: @FrankerZ but this will still redirect. I think what he needs is to set virtualhost to keep the links without showing the redirection path.

Comment: If you rewire a path without an explicit 301, it won't show a user a different path (This is what is used to SEO-ify websites), to remove index.php and other stuff